# How to determine what view controller presented the current view controller? (iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Depending on what view controller presented the current view controller, I need my current view controller to be dismissed by either of two presenting view controllers.

Here is the method in the current view controller:

```
-(void)goBack:(id)sender {
if ([self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[InitialViewController class]])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

else {
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

It doesn't work though. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should describe the architecture more. Are you sure this is a presented view controller situation and not a push/pop situation? If it is, what distinction are you trying to draw and what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, be aware that the view controller to whom you said `presentViewController` may not in fact be the `presentingViewController`. It is easy to get confused about this.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should be more precise. In some cases my current view controller is presented by SecondViewController which in case is presented by FirstViewController. In other cases my current view is presented by FirstViewController directly. My goal is that when current view controller is dismissed FirstViewController shows up.

Comment: In that case `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController` should work. It works on my machine.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you've written the condition wrong in the `if/else` test. Use logging to make sure the choice being taken is the one you expect.

Comment: yeah i think that the problem is in condition too. I have though no idea how to determine if presenting view controller is InitialViewController or SecondViewController

Comment: See my new answer. The problem is your `if` condition. Your logic is backwards.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your approach to dismissal (despite my earlier wrong answer!). What's wrong is your logic. The problem is this line:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[InitialViewController class]])
```

Change it to:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class])
```

That should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the view controller that presented a particular view controller, just do `viewController.presentingViewController`. That should always be set to whatever view controller presented the current view controller, that's the point of it. So if you want to dismiss the current view controller, do:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```